# Is there a way to stop referencing a child object in NHibernate without flushing the session or removing its parent from the session cache?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm building a standard old thick client with NHibernate where the majority of my entities (see `class A`) are dehydrated at application start and stay there for the app lifetime. These occassionally reference are a couple of very heavyweight classes (`class B`) that encapsulate a lot of data which are lazily loaded proxies so that they are only really fetched from the database on demand.

This works fine. The problem is I am wanting to also explicitly unload these B types later - from my point of view I want to go back to the state when they were uninitialized proxies and not taking up memory.

Seeing as there doesn't seem to be a way to de-initialize a proxy, I was planning on simply evicting `B` from the cache, removing all existing references to `B` (I realise I have to track them myself, this is fine) by replacing them with a new (uninitialized) B-proxy obtained from `session.Load<B>` (ie `a.MyB = session.Load<B>(oldId);`)

However it seems like NHibernate keeps a reference to the old `B` in the cache, and `B` won't be garbage collected until I either remove `A` from the cache or flushing the session.

I'm not sure why. I suspect it keeps the reference for the purposes of property comparison so it can see if it needs to push back to the database if I ever request a `session.SaveOrUpdate(a)`. But if  have set the relationship to not cascade so should it really matter?

The fluent mappings & tests bellow illustrate the matter. Use `Make()` to make the database and then `Load()` to run the test. Note that if you do uncomment the flush you will need to re-`Make()` again.

```
public class A
{
    internal int Id { get; private set; }

    public B B { get; set; }

    internal class Map : ClassMap<A>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Not.LazyLoad();
            References(x => x.B)
                .Cascade.None()
                .LazyLoad(Laziness.Proxy);
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    protected internal virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public virtual void Fizz()
    {
    }

    internal class Map : ClassMap<B>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            LazyLoad();
            References(x => x.A)
                .Cascade.None();
        }
    }

    private static ISessionFactory BuildSF(bool rebuilddb)
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
             .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("v.sqldb"))
             .Mappings(m =>
             {
                 m.FluentMappings.Add<A.Map>();
                 m.FluentMappings.Add<B.Map>();
             })
             .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
             {
                 //cfg.Interceptor = new Interceptor();
                 if (rebuilddb)
                     new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true);
             })
             .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Make()
    {
        var sessionFactory = BuildSF(true);
        var sess = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();
        a.B = b;
        b.A = a;

        sess.Save(a);
        sess.Save(b);
        sess.Flush();
    }


    [Test]
    public void Load()
    {
        var sessionFactory = BuildSF(false);
        var sess = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        var a = sess.Load<A>(1);

        // just loaded a, B should be a uninitialized proxy
        Assert.That(! NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(a.B)); 

        a.B.Fizz();
        // invoke on B, should now be initialized
        Assert.That(NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(a.B)); 

        var weakB = new WeakReference(a.B);

        sess.Evict(a.B);
        //sess.Evict(a); // uncomment this to pass the final test
        a.B = null;
        //sess.Flush(); // or this

        System.GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("Entities: " + sess.Statistics.EntityCount);
        foreach (var ek in sess.Statistics.EntityKeys)
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + ek.EntityName + " " + ek.Identifier);

        if (sess.Contains(a))
            Console.WriteLine("Session still contains a in cache");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Session no longer holds a");

        Assert.IsFalse(weakB.IsAlive);
    }
```

On the lower level my question is: can I remove this reference to the old B in some way without either removing A or flush?

On a higher level my question: how can I do what I want? My immediate thought to workaround this was to maybe just map and id on the A class and manually manage persistence/depersistence of B. But of course this bleeds persistence issues into my domain model a little, and my experience has been trying that to apply 'hacks' to NHibernate is usually a 'alice in wonderland down the rabbit hole' experience.

Comment: Maybe `IStatelessSession` would work? It bypasses the first-level cache entirely. I've never used it, though -- it is designed for bulk operations -- so I'm not sure it is applicable in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately I do still want a stateful session (unless I am misunderstanding your suggestion). The issue is not so much bulk operations as it is just singular heavy pocos I don't want hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

I find that for thick client or desktop applications the approach to NHibernate session management detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) is the only "workable" solution.  The jist of this solution is to keep most objects detached from a session unless they:

1. are being actively edited by a user
2. have been updated elsewhere in the app.  Use events to notify other view that they need to refresh their data

Note that I couldn't get stateless sessions to work per the MSDN article so I just use a normal session and then clear it when my transaction completes.